# Adding a line to a PHP File

Tags: c#

I want to add a line to a certain php file file through a void in C#.

How exactly could I do that?

------Edit------

The PHP file is on my Web Server, So I **do** have the details to connect to the website.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking, it's very unclear - please clarify, also it would be good to see what you have tried so far.

Comment: sorry, but wtf? What are you trying to do?

Comment: How do you get to the file, if you are editing it manually? Using FTP?

Answer (score 0):

Google your question before you ask it. We are not going to write the code for you.

For information on how to work with files in c# , go to  http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/anandctutorials/article.php/c5861

Comment: Sorry, Basically i need to write a file that is online on my web server, This doesn't really answer my question

Answer (score 0):

If you need write something to PHP file use this simple code:

```
File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/your_php_file.php"), "echo \"from C#\"");
```

Maybe it will help you but your question is unclear